# mysql - Find page of result record in pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, matching

imagine that we use pagination to split and display a mysql result like this,
sorted on auto inceremental ID and date:

```
SELECT name FROM members ORDER BY id DESC, date DESC LIMIT $start, $len
```

we display that result and page navigation links below it using php.

how we can find that record ID number x is in which page of that result so we set page number to that page and display that page and end-user do not need to click navigation and find it?

Comment: How looks the table of that database please?

Comment: name:varchar(100),date:DATETIME and id:INT PRIMARY AUTOINC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First get total number of records.

```
select count(*) as total from members;
```

Find the number of the row member 'x' is found in the record list

```
select count(*) oneLess from members where id < (select id from members where name='x');
```

The above query returns oneLess the record number from x. i.e. 'x' is oneLess+1

Now calculate the page number.

```
$asc_page_no =  floor((($oneLess+1)/$total)*$len);
$total_pages = floor($total/$len);
$page_no = $total_pages - $asc_page_no; //reverse the page looking direction
```

Then calculate $start

```
$start = $page_no * $len;
```

Comment: this have some bugs because we use DESC and not ASC and should count from end of page.

Comment: @exim That needs a very small change in a code. I updated my answer.

Comment: i think if the order list is set as DESC the conditional operator need to change into >

Answer (score 0):

@Bere have a nice solution but the problem is that your PRIMARY KEY is autoinc one so it is possible that 2 id are not consecutive ones.

You should add a column to put a number that you can control.

After use the program in the response of @Bere but don't use the primary key, use the new column.

Comment: but it can be huge number of records and I should use that index column.

Comment: What do you mean by huge? if the number is huge the ID should be too isn't it?

Comment: that will need extra calulation during each INSERT command. also imagine that end-users send several INSERT in milisecond to database so how we can count number and set it to new column? then we should lock database that is not good solution.

Comment: A trigger will do that for you. You just have to find MAX() + 1 and your insert should respect ACID properties so it should not have problem. The only way your database could have a problem is if you haave a really big app but in this case you would not use mysql to manage this amount of connections

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need to determine the page number where the desired row is:

```
SELECT d.myRowSerial, FLOOR((d.myRowSerial-1)/10) AS pageNumber
-- Say, 10 is per page;
FROM (
    SELECT *, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS myRowSerial 
    FROM myTable, (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS nothingButSetInitialValue 
    WHERE 1=1 -- Optional: filter if required, otherwise, omit this line;
    ORDER BY AnyColumn -- Apply the order you like; 
) d
WHERE d.myColumn = 'Anything'; -- If you like to limit it to only
-- for any specific row(s), similar to the *MAIN query.
```

You will have pageNumber==0 for page 1, and pageNumber==1 for page 2 and so on.....
Then we can simply calculate the OFFSET number with a simple calculation:

```
$offset = $myRowSerial * $perPage;
```

Now we can use this $offset value for our MAIN query.

Comment: This query is good if we check in top record but if we check in deep with milions of record, it will be to long

Answer (score 0):

As Reza Mamun offer his solution, it works fantastic... I want also create SELECT HTML element to navigate between pages. This require bit another approach.

For creating SELECT element I use array with 'name' and 'value' keys, so SQL query looks  that :

```
 $qry='
SELECT d.RowNumber, FLOOR( ( d.RowNumber ) / %s ) AS value, d.name 
    FROM( 
            SELECT  %s AS ID, 
                        %s AS name,
                        @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS RowNumber 
                FROM    %s, 
                        ( SELECT @rownum:=-1 ) AS Initialize 
                %s 
                %s 
         ) AS d
    WHERE d.Rownumber MOD %s = 0';


$sqry   = sprintf( $qry, $pagelength, $this->_tableindex, $sort_field, $this->_tablename, $cond, $sql_order, $pagelength );
```

query works with filtering by WHERE ( defined by user via form ), sorting ORDER BY (chosed by used ). I think the meaning of the variables and properties can be distinguished. This solution is intended for (almost) universal data pagging and user-defined page length.