# How can I search a paginator and find the page of an item?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my application, I have a comment section for each post and a reply section for each comment.

Since there can be many comments, I have setup two paginators:

- A comment paginator (?page=...)
- A reply paginator for each comment (?comment-(id)-page=...)

For the purpose of redirecting to a specific comment or reply by calling a method, how can I find the position of a comment in the comment paginator and do the same for replies?

Calling `$post->commentPaginator()->currentPage()` works inside views, but how can I perform a search to find the exact page of an item?

A method such as:
`$post->getCommentPage($comment)` (eg. 2) that would return the page where the comment is located at would be convenient.

Comment: I think you cannot do that in paginator itself. This requires another mysql query. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/18694483/3551175 . You already have items count, so you need only second query provided there.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're paginating by a timestamp, like `created_at`, I would try the following.

```
public function getCommentPage($comment, $reply)
{
    // How many items per page
    $repliesPerPage = 10;

    // Replies for this comment
    $replies = $comment->replies()->sortByDesc('created_at');

    // Find the rely position by its id
    $position = array_search($reply->id, array_keys($replies->toArray()));

    // Get the page position and always round up
    $page = ceil($position / $repliesPerPage);

    return page;
}
```